# Outputing $_ hashtable variables in a write-warning using a ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

so I'm trying to use this load of powershell from here: [Getting the current hash key in a ForEach-Object loop in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880725/getting-the-current-hash-key-in-a-foreach-object-loop-in-powershell)

```
$myHash.keys | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_["Entry 1"]
}
```

It's all working but I want to output the value as part of another string, i.e.:

```
$results.notvalid | ForEach-Object {
    write-warning 'Incorrect status code returned from $_["url"], 
                                                   code: $_["statuscode"]'
}
```

so I **want** the output to be:

> Incorrect status code returned from www.xxxx.com, code: 404

but **instead I get**

```
Incorrect status code returned from $_["url"], code: $_["statuscode"]
```

what am I missing?

---

*BTW, this works if I just do*

```
$results.notvalid | ForEach-Object {
        write-warning $_["url"]
    }
```

I then get

> www.xxxx.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer using format strings over embedded expressions (i.e.  `$()`).  I find it more readable.  Also, PowerShell creates properties on a hashtable for each key, so instead of indexing (i.e. `$_['url']`) you can `$_.url`.

```
$results.notvalid |
    ForEach-Object { 'Incorrect status code returned from {0}, code: {1}' 
                    -f $_.url,$_.statuscode } |
    Write-Warning
```

Answer (score 1):

You must put string in double quote instead of single quote if you want variables to be read. Also, in this spot you are not accessing directly a variable value, so you should use `$()` to be sure code to be evaluated in advance.

```
$results.notvalid | ForEach-Object {
    write-warning "Incorrect status code returned from $($_['url']), code: $($_['statuscode'])"
}
```